# Why are my factor levels turning to numbers with dplyr::mutate()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to recode some factor levels using dplyr::mutate(), so that all "MOT" and "CHI" factor levels remain as they are, and all others turn to "OTH".

My data looks like this:

```
subj | speaker | word

1        MOT     apple
1        CHI     baby
1        SI1     baby
2        CHI     dog
2        CHI     cat
2        FAT     cat
```

And I want it to looks like this:

```
subj | speaker | word

1        MOT     apple
1        CHI     baby
1        OTH     baby
2        CHI     dog
2        CHI     cat
2        OTH     cat
```

My code looks like this:

```
new.df <- data %>%
  dplyr::select(subj, speaker) %>%
        mutate(speaker = factor(speaker),
         speaker = ifelse(speaker %in% c("CHI", "MOT"), speaker, "OTH"))
```

However, when I run this script some of the levels are converted to "OTH" but all of the others change to numbers. This happens regardless of whether I include the factor(speaker) command:

```
subj | speaker | word

1        175     apple
1        86      baby
1        OTH     baby
2        86      dog
2        86      cat
2        OTH     cat
```

It is changing the factors to "OTH" ok but the TRUE element of my ifelse code appears to be the problem.

Many thanks!

Comment: You might want as.character(speaker) as your second argument to ifelse. R factors are actually integers. If speaker had been character then you were shooting yourself in the foot with the factor call coming before the ifelse operation. It might make sense after.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! But I don't understand why this would happen - when I omit the as.factor() command R tells me that speaker is already a character vector.

Comment: Factors in R are integers - integers that can be named when the factor is created.

Answer (score 2):

Why I am not sure exactly but if you read the help menu for factor: ?factor it mentions first converting to as.character.

```
new.df <- data %>%
dplyr::select(subj, speaker) %>%
    mutate(speaker = factor(speaker),
     speaker = ifelse(speaker %in% c("CHI", "MOT"), as.character(speaker), "OTH"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use this solution too as due to factor. This is generating index of the value present in the levels of factor.

```
new.df <- df %>%
select(subj, speaker) %>%
    mutate(speaker = ifelse(speaker %in% c("CHI", "MOT"), levels(speaker)
[speaker], "OTH"))
```

So to capture actual value we can use **levels(speaker)[speaker]**

Answer (score 1):

To change factors levels rather than the values in a character column, you'll need to work directly with the factor's levels.  You could do this in base R by working with the `levels` function or with the `fct_other` function in the `forcats` package from RStudio.  In both methods, `speaker` in `new.df` is a factor with the required levels.

These methods are shown below:

```
data <- data.frame(subj=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), speaker=c("MOT","CHI","SI1","CHI","CHI","FAT"), word=c("apply","baby","baby","dog","cat", "cat"))
#
# To reset selected levels in base R
#
  new.df <- data
  new.df$speaker <- factor(new.df$speaker)
  levels(new.df$speaker)[!levels(new.df$speaker) %in% c("CHI", "MOT")] <- "OTH"
#
# To reset using forcats package from the RStudio suite
#
  library(dplyr)
  library(forcats)
  new.df <- data %>% mutate(speaker = fct_other(speaker, keep=c("CHI","MOT"),
                                                other_level = "OTH"))
  #
  # Note that speaker in new.df is a factor with the new levels
  #
   str(new.df)
```